# Extract json objects to json in c#

Tags: c#, json, linq

i got an JArray in c# which i wannt to ***transpose/transform*** into :

[image]

Currently i do something like :

```
var mockDataPath = "...\\DummyData.json";
var rawJSON = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(mockDataPath);
JArray jArray = JArray.Parse(rawJSON);
```

Maybe linq will do the job, but i do not know how.

```
jArray.Children().Select(...);
```

And the objects (Obj2,Obj3) contain complex hierarchical data.

[Here an Link to a json pastiebin](https://www.pastiebin.com/5b1905ab2e261) with the original json data (this would be "...\DummyData.json")

I am looking for
[something like an XSL Transformation](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSL_Transformation)
for json. Or if LINQ will do the job, this would be even better.

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(arrayname);

Comment: use above statment and install newtonsoft json package

Comment: Why do 1 and 4 disappear?

Comment: just pass you array of object into the stament that is it .it will transform your array tto object of json

Comment: @imdisney What? Your suggestion makes as little sense as the question.

Comment: Voting to close as the desired results are unknown. I recommend editing your question to show some JSON inputs/outputs. For example, we still don't know why you keep 2 and 3, but not 1 and 4.

Comment: I already installed newtonsoft. I wannt to filter/transform the original json (like in the picture above to the transformed part) and do not know how

Comment: @user1911091 - ok so have you got a parent of the json object for Obj1, Obj 2, ..?

Comment: Apparently [there is a tool](https://github.com/Microsoft/json-document-transforms)

Comment: @Prany No, currently there is no parent.

Comment: @user1911091: Why are you deleting 1 and 4, but not 2 and 3? This question has been asked several times now and without this information, your question simply doesn't make enough sense to be able to answer it meaningfully.

Comment: Which kinda of filter we have to use to discard 1 and 4, and get 2 and 3 ? We can't help you if we dont know the critery

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Json.Net` to  `Deserialize` your json:

```
 Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.Deserialize("yuor json string");
```

Just look for `Newtonsoft.Json` in nuget Packages.

Comment: That does not answer the question about removing items 1 and 4.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did:

```
            JArray resultJArray = new JArray();
            foreach(JObject item in jArray)
            {
                JObject obj = JObject.FromObject( new { Obj2 = item.GetValue("Obj2"), Obj3 = item.GetValue("Obj3") } );
                resultJArray.Add(obj);
            }

            var transformedJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resultJArray, Formatting.Indented);
```